# Function that processes cells' values returning blank

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to loop through a range of cells and pass each cell into a function, that modifies its text and returns it. However, I can't get the below code to work as intended.

Any suggestions?

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("test").Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
    cell.Value = cleanCell(cell)
Next cell

Public Function cleanCell(cell As Range) As Variant

            If InStr(cell.Value, "US") > 0 Then
                If InStr(cell.Value, "US Test") > 0 Then
                Else
                    cell = Replace(cell.Value, " US", " US Test")
                End If
            End If
                  
End Function
```

Comment: Do you forgot `cleanCell = cell` before `End Function`?

Comment: Try using `cleanCell = Replace(cell.Value, " US", " US Test")` instead of `cell = Replace(cell.Value, " US", " US Test")`. `cell` is passed `byRef`.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
For Each cell In Worksheets("test").Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
    cell.Value = cleanCell(cell)
Next cell


Public Function cleanCell(cell As Range) As Variant
    Dim v
    v = cell.Value
    If InStr(v, " US") > 0 Then 'test with space ?
        If Not InStr(v, " US Test") > 0 Then
            v = Replace(v, " US", " US Test")
        End If
    End If
    cleanCell = v 'return original or modified value
End Function
```